# Dragon's Dogma - Where can I get a Gold Idol?

Tags: dragons-dogma, dragons-dogma-dark-arisen

I'm playing the Dark Arisen version for PS3.
So, I figured out the idols are important to get discounts and nice stuff on the shops, once you give them to the shop-owner as a gift.

I know I can get one if I complete successfully that mission in which you must be a play doll for that annoying kid Symone.
Problem is that I failed that mission, because I grabbed the kid when she fell. I thought I should pick her up and help her. But NO. I was arrested, mission failed, and the game saved immediatelly. In this game you can only have one save, which sucks. I tried to to that Checkpoint where you reset to the last Inn in which you've slept. I used it, but I would lose several hours of gameplay. Out of question.

So, is there another way of getting the gold idol? Or even repeating the mission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options to get a new gold idol, either you can get it by completing the game and replaying the quest in New Game Plus, or you can have it gifted to you through pawn hiring.  The good news is that the gold idol items from either vendor are surpassed by end game and Bitterblack Isle gear, so unless you wanted them for the looks they are not that important in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. But are there not some quests in which you need the idols?

Comment: @WerBn There are three idols in the game, and any one of them can be given to Caxton and Madeline to complete their quests.  The other two are lower quality (so they don't unlock full inventories), but you can't lock yourself out of getting them like the gold idol.

Comment: OkThanks! I'll handle these quests with the "low end" Idols then :D

Comment: @WerBn I apologize, I was wrong about locking yourself out of the other two - the lowest level idol, bronze, can always be obtained and can be forged to complete both quests, though the forgery will not improve the inventory.  Silver, the middle level, can only be obtained from a pawn guild quest which will become unavailable significantly later in the game.

Comment: Will the changes to the vendor I give the first gold idol to carry over to NG+? So I can give the second gold idol to another vendor? And reap the benefits of both vendors. @IllusiveBrian